# Laravel Pusher Websocket Not Working on HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, pusher-js

I'm using Laravel 5.8, and we're using a web socket with PUSHER in our application. It's broadcast perfectly locally or when I am on HTTP mode. When I update my set up to HTTPS, Broadcasting is no longer works.

```
Any hints on this ? anyone ?
```

I've tried

#Client Side

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    encrypted: false,
    // wsPort: 6001,
    // wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    forceTLS: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});
```

and

#Server Side

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'useTLS' => true,
        'debug' => true,
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4
        ]
    ],
],
```

Same Result! Not working!

[image]

It working perfectly on Chrome locally, but firefox

I see this in console

[image]

Comment: Any errors in your console log out network tab in your browser?

Comment: I don't see any error on network tab or console tab;

Comment: Try turning encrypted off? Usually when there's no log or error, make sure the driver is correctly set to pusher and the app_key should be the same. If then should out put handshake error or authentication error in front-end console.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman : I checked on firefox, I happen to see error on console as your predicted. now.

Comment: I think the port number is incorrect. You are connecting to port 6001, pusher uses the standard 443 for secure connections. See https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019420773-What-ports-do-I-need-to-open-in-my-Firewall-to-allow-Channels-to-connect-

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Do you think I should have 2 settings for local and prod ?

Comment: Also, is your server listening on 443?

Comment: @cyber8200 issue solved already?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not connecting to the correct port, or the default port is by Echo is not the default you should use for pusher. Define the correct port inside your JavaScript frontend `.env` file. (I don't know your repositories settings, but sometimes you can use a `.env.local` file, for example in a Vue setup).

Pusher seems to use default web ports 80 and 443, as described here: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol

After you defined the port inside your `.env`, change your JavaScript code:

```js
wsPort: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_WS_PORT, 
wssPort: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_WSS_PORT,
```

Don't forget to rebuild your frontend.

Comment: _Don't forget to rebuild your frontend_ and clear browser caches caching javascript files ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't write comments due to my low reputation, so I will write here:

> Try changing HTTP to HTTP**S** in **'scheme' => 'http'**

Check this option in websockets.php

> 'verify_peer' => false,

Also take a look at config samples in this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-configure-laravel-websockets-with-ssl-on-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned, this is happening locally, you may want to check out this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1187666) as it may be related to what you are experiencing... essentially there is a workaround outlined, to get firefox to work with self signed certificates, on sockets...

Additionally, what happens if you remove 'wss' from this your constructor:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    encrypted: false,
    // wsPort: 6001, <-- Should these be commented out?
    // wssPort: 6001, <-- Should these be commented out?
    disableStats: true,
    forceTLS: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws'] // removed wss
});
```

Furthermore, you have your ports commented out... that seems odd, as you need to have a port to the socket service.